# Add a statement, retaining the second parameter of the function

Tags: perl, unix, awk, sed

I have a huge file with lot of data.

I want to replace

```
Function_map(var33, 1.95);
```

with

```
Function_map(var33, 1.95);\nFunction_map(var18, 1.95);
```

Value of 1.95 varies.

ex:

1. Function_map(var33, 1.95); --> if present
   Function_map(var33, 1.95);
    Funcion_map(var18,1.95) --> add this line also in the file
2. Function_map(var33, 1.7);--> if present
       Function_map(var33, 1.7);
    Funcion_map(var18,1.7)--> add this line also in the file

Answer (score 3):

```
perl -i~ -pe '$_ .= "${1}18$2\n" if /(Function_map\(var) 33 (,[ ][0-9.]+\);)/x' input
```

Explanation:

- `-p` processes the file line by line
- `-i~` changes the file "in place", creates a `filename~` backup
- if the regular expression matches, everything before `33` is stored in $1, and everyting after it goes to $2; and those results with 18 in the middle are appended to the line to be printed.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're running version 10 or later of Perl 5, you can use the `\K` (keep) regex construct to write it like this. It allows for leading `+` or `-` signs on the floating point number

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my $s = 'Function_map(var33, 1.95);';

$s =~ s/Function_map\(var33,\s*([+\-0-9.]+)\);\K/\nFunction_map(var18, $1);/;

say $s;
```

**output**

```
Function_map(var33, 1.95);
Function_map(var18, 1.95);
```

If you are changing manually-entered code then you might like to add optional whitespace at the places where it makes no difference to the meaning of the statement. And it would be advantageous to use the `/x` modifier to allow you to add insignificant whitespace to the patter. Like this

```
$s =~ s{
    Function_map \s* \( var33 \s* , \s* ([+\-0-9.]+) \s* \) \s* ;
    \K
}{\nFunction_map(var18, $1);}x;
```

The result of this substitution is identical to that of the code above